# How can we improve the code related to the partition list?

Tags: java, spring, web, arraylist, partitioning

Each partition list has a different size.

I want to improve this code by selecting rxJava, stream etc...

Look at the code below and ask for comments.

```
public void testMethod(List<TestClass> list){
    List<List<TestClass>> subList1 = ListUtils.partition(list, 20);
    subList1.forEach(sub -> {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("list", sub);
        // LOGIC 1
    });

    List<List<TestClass>> subList2 = ListUtils.partition(list, 50);
    subList2.forEach(sub -> {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("list", sub);
        // LOGIC 2
    });

    List<List<TestClass>> subList3 = ListUtils.partition(list, 100);
    subList3.forEach(sub -> {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("list", sub);
        // LOGIC 3
    });

    List<List<TestClass>> subList4 = ListUtils.partition(list, 5);
    subList4.forEach(sub -> {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("list", sub);
        // LOGIC 4
    });
}
```

Comment: SO isn't really the place you should go to for a code review

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a CodeReview request: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/